# Understand the difference between pyspark.ml.regression 'IsotonicRegression' vs 'IsotonicRegressionModel'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to calibrate the output of an pyspark `GradientBoostingClassifier` model to probabilities and want to try [this option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression).

I have run an `IsotonicRegression` like this:

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import IsotonicRegression, IsotonicRegressionModel

model = IsotonicRegression().fit(train_data)
predictions_train=model.transform(test_data)
```

But I am unable to perform fit using `IsotonicRegressionModel` because when I try this:

```
irm = IsotonicRegressionModel()
model_irm  =irm.fit(train_data)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[70], line 4
      1 # Trains an isotonic regression model.
      2 irm = IsotonicRegressionModel()
----> 3 model_irm=irm.fit(train_data)

AttributeError: 'IsotonicRegressionModel' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

I would like to run second option to identify the difference between `IsotonicRegression` vs `IsotonicRegressionModel`.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me understand this difference.

Im using `spark.version 3.1.3`